# Exchange data between two identical hard drives

Tags: linux, hard-disk

I have two identical hard drives (same model) in my system. One is used for data which is not important (could be downloaded again but would take an eternity). The other is my system disk.
Now my problem is: The system disk is likely to fail in the near future (the SMART stats for it are really bad) and the other was seldom used and still has good stats.
Does anybody here now a program which can exchange the data between two drives without a third drive or losing data on one drive? I already ordered a new hard disk, but I want to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good answer but it's too long for a comment:

Depending on the data on each of the drives, you might try [compressing the `dd` image](https://serverfault.com/questions/52260/compressing-dd-backup-on-the-fly) of the most compressable HDD, then `dd` that drive to the next drive (using `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc` or whatever the drive names are), `dd` it back over the original drive (`sda` in my previous example) by doing a `gzcat` to pipe data into the final `dd` (similar to what they do [here](http://wiki.securityweekly.com/wiki/index.php/Pfsense#Get_pfSense_and_Install_on_CF_Card)).

You may also try to shrink the respective partitions as much as possible and only take a `dd` image of the individual partitions to see if that saves you more space.

Answer (score 0):

What you *don't* want to do is any solution that would cause unnecessary writes on Drive A.

If you're looking to *clone* the failing disk you'll want to use dd as indicated in Bratchley's answer.

If you're just looking to have a copy of the data for recovery purposes I would suggest using either tar or rsync.

```
tar -czvf /to/backup.tar.gz /from/path/

rsync -av /from/path/ /to/path/
```

Answer (score 0):

Also look into [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html). I discovered this the other day and it's quite brilliant. It will work like dd per Bratchley's answer, but it will also heroically recover from bad blocks it encounters.